# Rails 3 JQuery sort select list

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript

I'm using the build in CoffeeScript in Rails 3 to move items from one select list to another and back. This works with the following code:

```
$ ->
   $('#add').click (event) ->
     $('#geo_country_exclude option:selected').remove().appendTo('#geo_country_include');  

   $('#remove').click (event) ->
     $('#geo_country_include option:selected').remove().appendTo('#geo_country_exclude');
```

Code for select lists:

```
<%= select :geo, :country_exclude, @countries, {}, {:multiple => true, :size => 15} %>
<%= select :geo, :country_include, @countries, {}, {:multiple => true, :size => 15} %>
```

The problem is that it appends a new item to the end of the list. I would like the list to be sorted alphabetically again. How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to pull the `<option>`s out of the target `<select>`, add the option to that array, sort it by hand, and then replace the target `<select>`s `<option>`s with the sorted list. jQuery doesn't help that much with this sort of thing but the [low level DOM version](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLSelectElement) isn't terribly difficult, something like this:

```
exc = $('#geo_country_exclude')[0]
inc = $('#geo_country_include')[0]

by_option_value = (a, b) ->
    return +1 if(a.value > b.value)
    return -1 if(a.value < b.value)
    return  0

mv = (from, to) ->
    # to.options looks like an array and smells like an array but
    # it isn't an array so we employ the standard arrayification trick.
    opts = [].slice.call(to.options)
    # Move the <option>
    opts.push(from.options[from.selectedIndex])
    from.remove(from.selectedIndex)
    # Sort and replace.
    to.remove(0) for i in [ 0 ... to.options.length ]
    to.add(opt) for opt in opts.sort(by_option_value)

$('#add'   ).click (event) -> mv(exc, inc)
$('#remove').click (event) -> mv(inc, exc)
```

You might need to tweak the `by_option_value` comparison function and you might want to adjust the selected items in the `<select>`s after the move but you can sort that you easily enough.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/qRw3K/

If you need to deal with multi-selects then a minor modification to `mv` will do the trick:

```
mv = (from, to) ->
    opts = [].slice.call(to.options)
    while from.selectedIndex >= 0
        opts.push(from.options[from.selectedIndex])
        from.remove(from.selectedIndex)
    to.remove(0) for i in [ 0 ... to.options.length ]
    to.add(opt) for opt in opts.sort(by_option_value)
```

You just need to wrap the `opts.push` and `from.remove` in a little `while` loop.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/qRw3K/1/

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm. Unfortunately it can only transfer 1 option at a time. I have a select field where you can select multiple values at a time. How can I make it so that it transfers multiple values at a time? Thanks.

Comment: @SnelsNick: Sorry, I didn't see the `:multiple => true`, one moment.

Comment: @SnelsNick: You should be able to add a little `while` loop to sort out the multi-select, check my update please.